# How can I select this element?

Tags: css, select, dynamic, html

I have code blindness, it's like snowblindness, just wth far too much code.

I have a div class dynamically generated,

```
<div class="even last">
```

How can I select that with CSS?

```
div.even last {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding:2px;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work, and I just can't think more..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When multiple classes are specified with a space, it applies both of those classes to the element.

Therefore if you specify `div.even` AND/OR `div.last` it will use them.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have spaces in a css class name. This should work:

```
<div class="even_last"> 

div.even_last {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding:2px;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Spaces in css mean: the next element contained in the previous one, for example:

```
<div class="even_last">
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
    World
</div>

div.even_last div {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

*Hello* will be bold, while *World* will not.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it's gerneated, so I can't change the HTML to produce the underscore :)

Comment: You probably want to preserve the existing classes though. Both even and last are fairly standard when dealing with lists and tables.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then 'ck's answer will do for you.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the space with a dot and you're right:

```
div.even.last {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding:2px;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test page for this, and it styled the div, but nothing after that div would display at all.

Comment: Well, it is setting the height to 100%... without the HTML there's no point in speculating what it'll do. But this is the correct selector for matching div elements that are both 'even' and 'last'

Answer (score 0):

Name your class like `evenlast`:

```
div.evenlast
{
  /* styles here */
}
```